# Does there exist an analytic function $f(\frac{1}{n})^2 = \frac{n}{n+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Does there exist an analytic function $f(\frac{1}{n})^2 = \frac{n}{n+1}$ on (a) the complex plane and (b) the unit circle? If yes, how many? If no, why not?

I know I can write the function as: 
$f(\frac{1}{n}) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+1}$, so $f_{1}(z)=\sqrt{z+1}$ and $f_{2}(z)=-\sqrt{z+1}$. Now I have something to do with the identity theorem and accumulation points, but I'm not sure how this works... If someone could help me with this problem, that would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you assume that there can't be an analytic function $f$ such that $f(1/n)=(-1)^{k_n}\sqrt{\frac1n+1}$ for any arbitrary sequence $k_\bullet:\Bbb N_+\to\{0,1\}$, rather than just the constant ones?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path There are only two analytic branch of log that define complex square root. Take the positive and name it $f_1$. For an arbitrary sequence $k_n$  with no limit (this case is trivial), exists $k_{q_n}$ such than $k_{q_n}=0$ $\forall n$. So, $f_1(1/q_n) = f(1/q_n)$. By identity theorem, must be equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\frac n{n+1}=\frac1{1+1/n}$. There is an analytic function $f\colon\mathbb{D}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ satisfying your condition if and only if$$(\forall z\in\mathbb{D}):f^2(z)=\frac1{1+z},\tag1$$by the identity theorem. Consider $\log\colon\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,|z-1|<1\}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ defined by$$\log z=z-1-\frac{(z-1)^2}2+\frac{(z-1)^3}3+\cdots$$The you can take $f(z)=\pm\exp\left(\frac12\log(z+1)\right)$ and these are the only solutuions to your problem.

But if you replace $\mathbb D$ with $\mathbb C$, then there is no solution, because it follows from $(1)$ that $\lim_{z\to-1}f(z)$ does not exist.

Comment: Should not be $\lim_{z\to -1}f(z)$?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{D}$? Is this just a subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @RafaelGonzalezLopez I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Katie $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,|z|<1\}$.